# Display possible chord continuations in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, chord

Visual Studio (with or even without plug-ins) has many chord keys. By "chord" I mean a several consecutive presses, like

- Format Document <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>
- Extract Method (resharper) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

When I press the first combination, the status bar says:

> (Ctrk+K) was pressed. Waiting for second key of a chord...

I remember that Eclipse would display a **popup listing all possible continuations** when I press the first key of a chord.

Is it possible to achieve this in Visual Studio too? A plug-in perhaps? There's quite a lot of chords and I'd love to see a quick list with i.e. refactoring continuations after I press ReSharper's Ctrl+R, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just found [IntelliCommand extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/83f59659-abc1-4bfa-9779-42f687af0481), which seems to do exactly what you asked for. You can find more info in [this blogpost](http://outcoldman.com/en/blog/show/326):

> Also it shows the list of possible combination when you press first combination of chord shortcut keys, like Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C