# Visual studio 2013 won't accept an uppercase E

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts, capitalization

I have not (knowingly) created or reassigned any keyboard shortcuts, and thought that I should be at using only 'default' keyboard shortcuts. But when I attempt to type an uppercase 'E', the status bar displays,

> "(Shift+E) was pressed. Waiting for the second key of the chord..."

. If I hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> as suggested in the question, [How do you stop Visual Studio from waiting for the second part of a shortcut-combination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976289/how-do-you-stop-visual-studio-from-waiting-for-the-second-part-of-a-shortcut-com), the status bar displays,

> "The key combination (Shift+E, Esc) is not a command."

No other key combinations have produced an alternative outcome. This issue only exists for <kbd>E</kbd> and only exists in Visual Studio. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> isn't in any [Default Keyboard Shortcu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600331.aspx)t I saw on MSDN.

I installed the Intellicommand Extension as recommended in the [Display Possible Chord Continuations in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162282/display-possible-chord-continuations-in-visual-studio) discussion, but no prompts are displayed when I type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

Any suggestions for troubleshooting?

Comment: Try opening the currentsettings.vssettings file from your "Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Settings" folder in notepad.  See if there is anything interesting inside the <UserShortcuts> tag.

Comment: Have you installed any addins or extensions lately? Which file types are affected?

Comment: @OldFart - I took a look, and nothing appeared out of place. After closing, Visual Studio completely crashed. After uninstalling VS 2013 and installing VS 2015, everything is fine. Unfortunately, I never did figure out why I was having these errors.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I did install IIS 10.0 Express.

Answer (score 5):

Go to Tools > Options > Environment/Keyboard dialog.  Then put focus on the Press shortcut keys: textbox, do shift+E and see what comes up.  Once you find where it is set just update it to something else.

Comment: Tried this with Shift+E and nothing appears in the 'Shortcut currently used by:' drop down. (Works fine with Ctrl commands).  I've also tried resetting the default keyboard mapping scheme without any luck.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you.  Sounds like VS doesn't think it's a shortcut key, even though it's treating it like one.  If it were me I would explicitly set a shortcut up using shift+E, then remove it, just to see if that'll straighten out this strange and buggy behavior.

Answer (score 3):

I've just noticed this problem, removed the PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio extension, which I updated the other day and now Shift-E works again...

Answer (score 1):

Just had this happen to me.

Can confirm its definitely caused by the PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio extension.

Pressing Shift+E in the Keyboard dialogue didn't bring up anything, however having read responses to this post about it possibly being related to the mentioned extension searched for PowerShell in the "Show commands containing:" box. It brings up a few, and the second one down for me "EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.PowerShell.ExecuteAsAScript" had Shift+E, F5. I removed this shortcut and now Shift+E is working fine.

Comment: Glad you were able to get rid of the issue without any critical failures!

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio's behaving like you have something bound to `Shift-E, _`.

Since you say you haven't set up any keybindings, have you tried following [MSDN's instructions on resetting your environment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbhkx167.aspx#bkmk_reverting)?

Comment: I tried resetting these without any success. Ultimately I opted to install Visual Studio 2015 and uninstall the broken Visual Studio 2013. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, but manage to get rid of it.

Most probable cause for me was extension "PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio".
Additionaly, I've disabled keyboard shortcuts synchronization in Tools>Options>Synchronized Settings and restored default keyboard mapping scheme as well.

Hope that helps!